# Concurrent gremlin-server and graph queries in java

Tags: java, server, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I'm writing a Java application with TinkerPop3. It communicates with a Neo4j graph and sends read/write queries through Gremlin using the `neo4j-gremlin 3.0.0.M7` libraries.

Concurrently, I would like to make this graph available through HTTP using `gremlin-server 3.0.0.M7`. Separately, these operations work perfectly fine. However, it seems that this is not possible concurrently due to multiple connections not being allowed (i.e. the `GremlinServer` object and the Java code both try to obtain the lock on the graph).

Of course, a workaround could involve creating a Client from within the Java program and connect it to the server. However, I would rather eliminate the communication overhead this introduces.

The big question: is this possible?

For completeness, here's my minimal code. Note that my `gremlin-server-neo4j.yaml` refers to the standardly included `neo4j-empty.properties` file, containing the same neo4j graph data directory as the Neo4jGraph object in my Java code (i.e. `/tmp/neo4j`).

```
import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph;
import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer;
import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.Settings;    

public class Main {

    Neo4jGraph g;
    GremlinServer s;

    public static void main (String[] argv) {
        new Main().start();
    }

    private void start () {

        try {
            Settings settings = Settings.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/gremlin-server-neo4j.yaml"));
            s = new GremlinServer(settings);
            s.run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        g = Neo4jGraph.open("/tmp/neo4j");

        // Gremlin code here

        g.close();
        s.stop();
    }
}
```

And, finally, the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, /tmp/neo4j
    at com.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph.<init>(Neo4jGraph.java:160)
    at com.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph.open(Neo4jGraph.java:175)
    at com.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph.open(Neo4jGraph.java:184)
    at org.test.Main.start(Main.java:33)
    at org.test.Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, /tmp/neo4j
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:366)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:91)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:181)
    at com.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph.<init>(Neo4jGraph.java:133)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter@67ec8477' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:343)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Unable to obtain lock on store lock file: /tmp/neo4j/store_lock. Please ensure no other process is using this database, and that the directory is writable (required even for read-only access)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:82)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.start(StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.java:44)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to lock org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFileChannel@baf1bb3
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.FileLock.wrapFileChannelLock(FileLock.java:38)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.FileLock.getOsSpecificFileLock(FileLock.java:93)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.tryLock(DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.java:93)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:74)
    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've found, what you are trying to do won't work because two separate processes cannot work on the embedded `Neo4jGraph`.  As it stands you can't get access to the configured graph instances from the `GremlinServer` object and I'm not sure I'd change that as I'm not completely sure that this is a feature that would be useful to everyone.

It looks to me like what you need is a way to "initialize" your `Graph` instance.  If so, then Gremlin Server offers a way to do that.  You can supply an initialization script in the yaml file (the below is a snippet from `conf/gremlin-server-classic.yaml` which is packaged with Gremlin Server distribution).

```
scriptEngines: {
  gremlin-groovy: {
    imports: [java.lang.Math],
    staticImports: [java.lang.Math.PI],
    scripts: [scripts/generate-classic.groovy]}}
```

Note the "scripts" key which lets you supply script files to execute.  Those scripts will yield you access to "g" (or whatever graphs you have configured).  For this example, `scripts/generate-classic.groovy` just has:

```
TinkerFactory.generateClassic(g)
```

In this way you can do all your initialization work on the `Graph` that will ultimately be hosted by Gremlin Server when it starts and can then simply start it all up in the standard way with `bin/gremlin-server.sh`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Does this mean that the server won't start serving until the specified scripts have completed running? In my particular application, I would like to execute a script that keeps running concurrently with the server, but as I understand it, such a script is meant to be an initialization step only (holding the lock until finished, allowing the server to grab the lock afterwards). Would making such a script run forever result in the server never starting?

Comment: An initialization script will block until it finishes executing.  So the server won't start serving until that completes.  If you want to have that script continuously running for the life of the server (and avoid the block), I suppose you'd have to start a separate thread in your script.  The problem with that is how you would stop that thread nicely as there won't be a trigger to know when the server is shutting down.  I'm not opposed to a change to Gremlin Server to provide that hook as a binding accessible from the script.  See this issue: https://github.com/tinkerpop/tinkerpop3/issues/553

Comment: Okay, then I'll use the client approach for now. Thanks for your help!